# activeadmin + internationalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I've updated active_admin to version 0.3.0 to get internationalization working. But I have problems with it.

I have my pl.yml file updated with activeadmin section which looks like this:

```
pl:  
  active_admin:
    blank_slate:
      content: "Nie ma jeszcze rekordów."
      link: "Nowy"
    dashboard: "Dashboard2"
    view: "Podgląd"
```

This didn't work, so I tried adding this code to my application.rb:

```
    config.before_configuration do
      I18n.locale = :pl
      I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*', '.{rb,yml}')]
      I18n.reload!
    end
```

Now internationalization seems to work in development environment, but I still have problems in other environments. I have problem with dashboard: key. Normally, in short, when I18n doesn't find the key it puts key: with capital letter, in this example it would be "Dashboard". But in my case i have something like this:

Develoment:
[image: Development]

Production:
[image: Production]

Is there anyone who had the same problem? I'm I doing something wrong, or is this an activeadmin bug? Any solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. I needed to do this to be able to get it to work in both production and development:

```
config.before_configuration do
  I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  I18n.locale = :nl
  I18n.default_locale = :nl
  config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  config.i18n.locale = :nl
  # bypasses rails bug with i18n in production\
  I18n.reload!
  config.i18n.reload!
end

config.i18n.locale = :nl
config.i18n.default_locale = :nl
```

Not very pretty, but probably caused by a bug in Rails.

Comment: thank you! it did the job, but still - it's just a workaround. Waiting for them to fix this. ; )

Comment: This bug is partially fixed on latest version.
see https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/434

Answer (score 4):

in application.rb

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
I18n.locale = config.i18n.locale = config.i18n.default_locale
I18n.reload!
```

Answer (score 2):

The key reason maybe caused by : Rails chose the locale from enduser's browser, but not your config file. e.g. a Japanese is visiting your website with his browser using English , then your Rails app will show him the "English" text, but not Japanese that you want it to show.

According to Rails i18n document: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html, you have to first of all:

1. edit config/application.rb to set the default_locale

   ```
   config.i18n.default_locale = :cn
   ```
2. edit your app/controllers/application_controller.rb, to add a before_filter

   ```
   before_filter :set_locale
   # for those user whose browser is not using our default_locale, e.g. a Chinese using English broser,
   # just like me. :)
   def set_locale
     I18n.locale = params[:local] || I18n.default_locale
   end
   ```
3. in this case, you should have the "cn" as the default locale.
4. check your view page, by adding these line of code to any of your page. e.g.

   ```
   # in products/index.html.erb
   <h1>Products List</h1>
   default_locale is: <%= I18n.default_locale %> <br/>
   current_locale is: <%= I18n.locale %>
   ```
5. the output result should look like:

   ```
   Products List
   default_locale is: cn 
   current_locale is: cn
   ```

   and your Rails application should work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that seems to work is creating an initializer with the following:

```
# config/initializers/i18n_reload.rb
Rails.configuration.after_initialize do
  I18n.reload!
end
```